# Is there a way to programmatically associate a variable and a target object with the control in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, addtarget

I'm creating a slider programmatically due to and Xcode bug, (don't let me center the thumb when I change the slider values, so I decided to do it using code) and I want to have a variable which saves the slider value. Is there a way to associate the variable and the target object with the control, similar to "addTarget", but instead of an action, its a variable?
I don't know if I explained myself but tell me if I need to be more specific. Thanks in advance :) for helping me.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit 
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderVar: UISlider!
    var currentSliderValue = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 98, y: 173, width: 699, height: 30))
      slider.center = self.view.center
      slider.minimumValue = 1
      slider.maximumValue = 100
      slider.value = 50
      slider.isContinuous = true
      slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderMoved(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
      self.view.addSubview(slider)
    }

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(_ sender: UISlider) {
      currentSliderValue = lroundf(sender.value)
    }
}
```

My function “sliderMoved” changes the sliderCurrentValue variable, but this var won’t change until I use the slider and move it. I also have a button there, that when you touch it up it shows the slider value, but the “sliderCurrentValue” only changes its value when the slider is moved. I was thinking of creating an IBOutlet but I don’t know how to connect this one with the slider.

Comment: Are you looking for [`NSControl.target`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428885-target) (which NSSlider inherits)?

Comment: IDK about whether or not Interface builder can center the knob or not, but even if it doesn't, that doesn't mean you need to create the control entirely from code. You can create it in Interface Builder, connect it to an `@IBOutlet` in your View Controller, and center the knob position in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I did it with the second option, cause I'm not sure how to do it w the first one, thank u so much tho

Comment: Are you familiar with `@IBOutlet`s?

Comment: add a code sample

Comment: Alexander yuppp

Comment: I just added the code sample, Rachel :)

Comment: Can you describe your needs in terms of expected inputs and outputs of this control and associated variable?

Comment: I edited my post, ilya. Idk if it’s better explained

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to bind variable to slider's value. There are several ways to achieve it. There is one way. Declare variable with custom setters and getters

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var slider: UISlider!

  var sliderValue: Float {
    set {
      // use optional chaining here helps avoid crashes 
      slider?.setValue(newValue, animated: true)
    }
    get {
      // if slider control hasn't created yet you need to return some dummy value
      slider?.value ?? -1
    }
  }

  func viewDidLoad() {
    // your current implementation here
  }
}
```